# Using InOrder to verify method calls with List object that changes

Tags: java, mockito

I have a callback interface that has a method which takes a `List` object.  I want to use `InOrder` to verify that the callback method is called the appropriate number of times, in the correct order, with the correct parameters.

The problem is that Mockito seems to be getting confused because I am passing the same `List` object into the method and modifying it between invocations.  When I call `InOrder.verify()`, I want to verify the value of the `List` object *at the time in which that method invocation was executed*.

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Callback callback = Mockito.mock(Callback.class);
        InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(callback);

        {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //note: this List object is inaccessible from the unit test in my real use-case
            callback.foo("name1", list);
            list.add("value");
            callback.foo("name2", list);
        }

        inOrder.verify(callback).foo("name1", Arrays.<String> asList()); //fails here
        inOrder.verify(callback).foo("name2", Arrays.asList("value"));
    }

    interface Callback {
        void foo(String name, List<String> list);
    }
}
```

**Error message:**

```
Argument(s) are different!  Wanted:
callback.onFoo([]);
Actual invocation has different arguments:
callback.onFoo([value]);
```

Passing a **copy** of the `List` object into each callback method invocation makes the test pass.  But I don't want to create a new `List` every time the method is called.

I looked at the `MockSettings` object you can pass into `Mockito.mock()`, but didn't see anything that might help.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24074218) is similar to mine.  But the solution does not verify the content of the collection that was passed into each method call--it only verifies the fact that *some collection* was passed into it (`anyCollectionOf()`).  It verifies the *end result*, but *not the individual invocations*.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505864/13379) seemed to provide a potential solution.  It uses `ArgumentCaptor` to capture the object that is passed into the method.  But when I use it to verify the first method call, it returns the `List` object *after all the modifications were made to it*, thus failing the test.  I need it to return a `List` object whose state matches the `List` object's state *at that precise invocation*.

```
ArgumentCaptor<List> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);

inOrder.verify(callback).foo(Mockito.eq("name1"), argument.capture());
assertEquals(Arrays.asList(), argument.getValue()); //fails: "expected: <[]> but was: <[value]>

inOrder.verify(callback).foo(Mockito.eq("name2"), argument.capture());
assertEquals(Arrays.asList("value"), argument.getValue());
```

How can I get this test to pass without sacrificing any granularity?

Comment: If you are going to use my anser in the duplicate suggested by me, you would create a copy of the list in the capturing function. And afterwards during the verification phase you could inspect those copies for them to be correct.

Comment: Thank you @SpaceTrucker.  Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [question that @SpaceTrucker linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36573399/13379) provided a solution.

Basically, create a custom `Answer` for the method and store a copy of the `List` argument every time the method is called.  Then, verify that all of the copies are what you expect them to be.  It's not ideal, but it works.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Callback callback = Mockito.mock(Callback.class);

    final List<List<String>> listParameters = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            List<String> list = (List<String>) invocation.getArguments()[1];
            listParameters.add(new ArrayList<String>(list));
            return null;
        }
    }).when(callback).foo(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyList());

    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //note: this List object is inaccessible from the unit test in my real use-case
        callback.foo("name1", list);
        list.add("value");
        callback.foo("name2", list);
    }

    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(callback);
    inOrder.verify(callback).foo(Mockito.eq("name1"), Mockito.anyList());
    inOrder.verify(callback).foo(Mockito.eq("name2"), Mockito.anyList());

    Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList(),
        Arrays.asList("value")
    ), listParameters);
}
```

Comment: If you say "It's not ideal", what do you think could be better?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker It would be better if my original code worked.  The solution is verbose and does not read well.